# I installed openSUSE Leap 15.4 and it won't reach to log in

Tags: boot, opensuse

i'm a switching from windows to linux and my chosen os is OpenSUSE.

Installation took 4 hours to install, i don't know if it is normal or not but i let it do its thing. Waited for it to install and then after installation,it wont reach to log in. Just loading screen.

here's what i get when i press the ESC button:

[image]

Please, badly need help :)

Comment: no, 4 hours is not normal, and it usually points to some hardware problems.

Comment: hi, what could be the possible fix?

Comment: you have downloaded OpenSUSE iso and put it on usb (or which medium?). Did you start with installing or just trying it? If you run trying OpenSUSE, is all ok?

Comment: hi, yes i put it on usb and i did not tried it at first, i continued the installation right away.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode? You should be able to enter single user mode - at grub, press `e` to edit the boot line, scroll down to the /linux/ entry then add ` 1` at the end, then <F10> to boot with it.

Comment: @Marione then do it now - boot the usb with iso, choose try and see if it runs at all on your computer, and if it runs, maybe you didn't like it. What were your reasons to choose OpenSUSE?